# Size difference between massif visualizer and ms_print

Tags: c++, valgrind, visualizer, massif

I have been trying to use valgrind memory usage tool massif. But I have a problem when I try to visualize the output of valgrind --massif output .out with programs ms_print and massiff visualizer app.

There is a difference of 2KiB between ms_print and massiff visualizer app (http://milianw.de/tag/massif-visualizer).

Is there anything I am missing ? I have added screenshots of both.

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, 1KiB = 1024B. So 71KiB = 72704B.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the clarification.